# Как создать справочник в 1с?

Tags: 1с

Реквизиты, табличные части и формы создала , а как написать для них обработку?

Я работаю на 8.2 "тонкий клиент".

Answer (score 3):

Лика, Ваш вопрос, к сожалению, неполный.

Не указана версия 1С (7.5, 7.7, 8.0, 8.1, 8.2), если «восьмерка», то какой режим работы со справочником предполагается для пользователя: «тонкий клиент» или «управляемое приложение», будет код обработки выполнятся на сервере или на клиенте...

Для начинающего «восьмерочника» могу порекомендовать книгу М.Г.Радченко  «1С:Предприятие 8.1 Практическое пособие разработчика». Она часто встречается в торрентах, да и купить её не так уж дорого.

Comment: а чтонибудь более нормальное чем Радченко есть в мире 1С? НАчал изучать - купил комплект для обучений - начал читать - вот нифига не понял - сразу желание отбилось, хотя знаком с другими языками программирования. 
И вот случай вспонил - пришел к нам на работу 1С-ник - хотели наладить связь 1С c инет магазином - я его спрашиваю - давай те дам дамп базы - а он меня спрашивает - а что это? 
ТО есть такое чувство, что 1С-ники вообще как то поверхностно знакомы с базами и с чем их кушают

Comment: @Ale_x Ну не все 1С-ники настолько зелены. Похоже вам попался совсем молодой специалист. Для нормального 1С-программиста создать дамп базы перед началом своей работы - это как отче наш. А по поводу научиться программированию в 1С для людей, которые в первый раз видят конфигуратор я бы посоветовал книги: ["Hello, 1C", В. Рыбалка](http://v8.1c.ru/metod/books/book.jsp?id=195). Или небольшой видеокурс [как разработать простое прикладное решение](http://v8.1c.ru/metod/videotutorial/r002.html). Ну и немного своей рекламки (прошу не бить). Веду [сайт по программированию в 1С](http://nastroy-ka.ru).

Comment: Есть, конечно. Но для ответа именно на этот вопрос данной книги будет достаточно. Т.б. что она дает и примеры разработки и именно для новичка.
Простите, но, ИМХО, развитие священной войны "радченко" против "нект" будет оффтопом в данной теме. :)

Comment: о какой войне то идет речь?

Comment: @AOkipniy, ок, погляжу ваши ссылки.

Comment: А еще есть различие в терминологии. Можно сказать дамп, снапшот или, как в 1С, выгрузить информационную базу))) По 1с советую великолепный видео курс Павла Чистова [link text http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3484928] [1]  


  [1]: http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3484928